# Is this Rust code that uses the Windows API "safe"?

Tags: winapi, rust

```
use winapi::um::processthreadsapi::OpenProcess;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::{DWORD, FALSE};
use winapi::shared::ntdef::NULL;
use winapi::um::winnt::{HANDLE, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS};
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;

pub fn get_process_full_access(process_id: DWORD) -> Result<HANDLE, DWORD> {
    unsafe {
        let process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, process_id);
        if process == NULL {
            Err(GetLastError())
        } else {
            Ok(process)
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this function using Rust's bindings to the Windows API and I *think* that I covered at least the documented error cases for the `OpenProcess` function, but I am still very unsure about the actual safety of my code.

I know Rust makes guarantees related to preventing race conditions, but I don't really know what to look for to make sure that my code makes those same guarantees. In situations like this should I just make the wrapping function unsafe as well, or is it worth it to prevent unsafe from bubbling up in my programs?

Comment: *is it worth it to prevent unsafe from bubbling up in my programs* — yes. That's kind of the entire point of Rust, to me: providing safe abstractions. Without that firewall, you might as well write C which "automatically adds `unsafe`" to every function and statement.

Comment: *makes guarantees related to preventing race conditions* — not in the most general sense, it doesn't. It only cares about *data races*, not logical race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a race on the process id. To be race free you would have to verify that the pid matches the expected process start time (the restart manager uses [`RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373677(v=vs.85).aspx) for this). Ideally you would keep the handle from your created child processes instead, a process id cannot be reused as long as somebody has a open handle to the process.

If it is not your child process and you don't have a handle then you have to get the system time before finding the process id and calling `get_process_full_access`, then call [`GetProcessTimes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) on the process handle and verify that the creation time is older than the time you read **before finding the process id** and opening the process.

Comment: While this answer points out logical issues with the OPs code, it doesn't address the question that the OP asked ("is it safe"). "Safety" has [a very specific meaning in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/unsafety.html), which this answer doesn't address. It's probable that the OP doesn't even intend to ask about this specific meaning of safety (or has misunderstood what it means). The answer to OPs question, as far as I can tell, is **yes**.

Comment: /libstd/sys/windows/process.rs puts its WinAPI calls in unsafe blocks but I don't know Rust well enough to know what the semantics of a handle is supposed to be. That code also has a process struct that uses a process handle, not a process id and you should be using that struct when possible.

Comment: Calling *any* FFI function has to be in an unsafe block because the compiler doesn't know what it might do. By building an abstraction around the FFI functions, the standard library makes spawning a process a safe operation.

Comment: @Shepmaster I did intend to ask about rust's specific meaning of safety, though I guess I did not get that across.

Comment: @Anders I'm not creating child processes in the application as a whole, I am reading into the memory of a separate process. I don't know if that informs your answer or not.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that doesn't speak to Rust safety? That was quite clear from the question. Anyone who knows Rust would recognise that clearly.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/636497/does-windows-7-reuse-process-ids suggests process id collisions are actually a real problem, so this answer adds something useful. Still, the function is safe regarding rust expectations.

Comment: @Stefan Who said anything about adding something useful. I'm talking about how SO works where answers must address the question asked. If you want to add asides, then that's for comments.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Windows API implements the basic exception guarantee: A function either runs to completion, or returns an error. In either case, no invariants are violated. Regarding the [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) API, there are only two outcomes:

- The function fails (signaled by a return value of `NULL`).
- The function succeeds and returns a `HANDLE` that remains valid until `CloseHandle` is called on it.

The implementation of `get_process_full_access` accounts for all outcomes, and propagates the results accordingly. As such, it is safe and need not be marked `unsafe`.

Yet, the *interface* still isn't safe: It returns a raw `HANDLE` value, that doesn't release its referenced resources when it gets dropped. This would need to be wrapped in a struct, that implements - at the very least - the [Drop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait (though [Clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) wouldn't hurt either):

```
pub struct KernelObj {
    handle: HANDLE,
}

impl Drop for KernelObj {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { CloseHandle( self.handle ) };
    }
}
```

The implementation would need to be updated like so:

```
pub fn get_process_full_access(process_id: DWORD) -> Result<KernelObj, DWORD> {
    unsafe {
        let process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, process_id);
        if process == NULL {
            Err(GetLastError())
        } else {
            Ok(KernelObj{ handle: process })
        }
    }
}
```

`clone()` would have to call [DuplicateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle). Again, optionally, you could implement the [Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) and [Send](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) marker traits, as both concurrent shared access, as well as transfer to arbitrary threads are safe operations.